# Datatables Not Sorting on one of the columns

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, datatables

This is my first time using datatables and I am having a few issues with the plugin. First of all, it is working great all around except it does not like to sort on the Date column or a "Success" column which is just 1 character. For the rest of the columns, it will sort without a problem. I am using paging and loading 10 rows at a time.

This is my HTML:

```
<head>
<link href="styles/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>    
<link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="styles/jquery-dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-dataTables-columnFilter.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no,width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#dt_op').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "./test.cfm",
                "iDisplayStart": 0,
                //Table is initially sorted on 3rd col in Desc order.number
                //Which is DateTime Visited in this case.
                "aaSorting": [[3, "desc"]]
                /*"aoColumnsDefs":
                [
                    {"sType": "date", "aTargets": [5]},
                    {"sType": "string", "aTargets": [6]}
                ]*/
            });
            $('#dt_op').dataTable().columnFilter({
                aoColumns:
                [
                    null, null, null, 
                    {type: "select", values: ['Web', 'Mobile']},
                    {type: "select", values: ['Windows Phone', 'iPhone', 'iPad', 'Android Mobile', 'Android Tablet', 'Other/Desktop']},
                    {type: "date-range"},
                    {type: "select", values: ['Y', 'N', 'X']}
                ]


            });
        } );
    </script>
</head>
<body id="dt_op_body">

<div id="container">

<table cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0" border="1" id="dt_op">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="10%">IP Address</th>
                <th width="50%">User Agent</th>
                <th width="10%">Platform Category</th>
                <th width="10%">Platform</th>
                <th width="20%">Date/Time Visited</th>
                <th width="10%">Successful Login</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">Loading Data from Server</td>   
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Platform Category</th>
                <th>Platform</th>
                <th>Date/Time Visited</th>
                <th>Successful Login</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

And this is the AJAX file being read:

```
<!--- table name --->
<cfset sTableName = "login_activity2" />

<!--- list of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables --->
<cfset listColumns = "remote_addr,user_agent,visited_on,login_success" />

<!--- Indexed column --->
<cfset sIndexColumn = "id" />

<!--- Paging --->
<!--- ColdFusion Specific Note: I am handling paging in the cfoutput statement instead of limit. --->

<cfparam name="url.iDisplayStart" default="0" type="integer" />
<cfparam name="url.iDisplayLength" default="10" type="integer" />

<!--- Filtering --->
<cfparam name="url.sSearch" default="" type="string" />

<!--- Ordering --->
<cfparam name="url.iSortingCols" default="0" type="integer" />

<cfquery datasource="#SQL#" name="getUserMetaData2" password="#password#" username="#username#"
        cachedwithin="#createTimespan(0,0,1,0)#">
    SELECT #listColumns#
        FROM #sTableName#
    <cfif len(trim(url.sSearch))>
        WHERE 
        <cfloop list="#listColumns#" index="thisColumn">
            <cfif thisColumn neq listFirst(listColumns)> OR </cfif>#thisColumn# LIKE 

            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="%#trim(url.sSearch)#%" />
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
    <cfif url.iSortingCols gt 0>
        ORDER BY 
        <cfloop from="0" to="#url.iSortingCols-1#" index="thisS">
            <cfif thisS is not 0>, </cfif>#listGetAt(listColumns(url["iSortCol_"&thisS]+1))# 
            <cfif listFindNoCase("asc,desc",url["sSortDir_"&thisS]) gt 0>#url["sSortDir_"&thisS]#</cfif> 
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
</cfquery>

<cfquery datasource="#SQL#" name="getUserMetaDataCount" password="#password#" username="#username#">
    SELECT COUNT(#sIndexColumn#) as total
    FROM #sTableName#
</cfquery>
<!--- Creates and passes JSON object with operational info in it --->
<cfcontent reset="Yes" />
{
    "sEcho": <cfoutput>#val(url.sEcho)#</cfoutput>,
    "iTotalRecords": <cfoutput>#getUserMetaDataCount.total#</cfoutput>,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": <cfoutput>#getUserMetaData2.recordCount#</cfoutput>,


"aaData": 


[
<cfoutput query="getUserMetaData2" startrow="#val(url.iDisplayStart+1)#" maxrows="#val(url.iDisplayLength)#">
<cfif currentRow gt (url.iDisplayStart+1)>,</cfif>
[
<cfloop list="#listColumns#" index="thisColumn">
<cfif thisColumn neq listFirst(listColumns)>,</cfif>
"#jsStringFormat(getUserMetaData2[thisColumn][getUserMetaData2.currentRow])#"
<cfif thisColumn eq 'user_agent'>
<!--- Add Comma to deliminate JSON fields properly --->
,
<cfset client.platform_category = "Mobile">
<cfset userAgent = getUserMetaData2[thisColumn][getUserMetaData2.currentRow]>
<cfif findNoCase('Windows Phone', userAgent, 1)>
    <cfset client.platform = "Windows Phone">
<cfelseif findNoCase('iPhone', userAgent, 1)>
    <cfset client.platform = "iPhone">
<cfelseif findNoCase('iPad', userAgent, 1)>
    <cfset client.platform = "iPad">
<cfelseif findNoCase('Android', userAgent, 1) AND findNoCase('Mobile', thisColumn, 1)>
    <cfset client.platform = "Android Mobile">
<cfelseif findNoCase('Android', userAgent, 1)>
    <cfset client.platform = "Android Tablet">
<cfelse>
    <cfset client.platform = "Other/Desktop">
    <cfset client.platform_category = "Web">
</cfif>


"#client.platform_category#",
"#client.platform#" 

</cfif>
</cfloop>
]
</cfoutput> 
] 
}
```

I can sort on all columns fine except that last two. I have it set so it is sorted by date desc on load but if I try to sort it again, I am getting the "Processing" screen for a long time and it never finishes. I am not sure why it is just these two fields causing issues. I have tried setting up indexes, but it is no help. The SQL Statement runs without issue in Management Studio so I am at a loss as to what the actual issue may be. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I think the best thing to do would be to utilize a tool like firebug or the chrome development tools to investigate what errors your code is throwing.  As I recall generally the processing screen hanging like that coincides with an error.

Comment: You probably need to paste the raw JSON that is produced by your code Dustin. This will likely come down to what the database is producing for your date. You will likely have to add a format to your output for your date columns to conform to whatever jQuery expects as "date".

Comment: In addition to firebug/chrometools, during these debug issues i will create a new node after aaData that writes the sql being executed , i then copy/paste in sql editor to run/check errors

Comment: Also, using jsFormat can lead to issues with apostrophe encoding, do any of your columns have apostrophes? I.e. should be using serializeJSON

Comment: Last thing i'll say is that i recently did a CF datatables implementation, there are many improvements i've devised (using the column list from query rather than a separate column array) i'd be glad to share if needed

Comment: I was able to get it to work yesterday. It appears that my addition of custom columns that were not in the database were not liked by the sorting functions.

Jay -- If you wouldn't mind sharing those, that would be wonderful :)